# Can I assign the directory above my script as a variable in powershell?

Tags: variables, powershell, dictionary, directory

Say I have the folder named "Program". In there, a folder named "Script" exists. The "Script" folder is where my Powershell file (.ps1) is. Is there any way to assign the folder "Program" to my powershell script? I am using this as a way to assign the variable of the current dictionary:

```
$currentDirectory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
```

Can I assign the dictionary "Program" using a method similar to this one?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Split-Path` with `-Parent` parameter; e.g.:

```
# $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path contains path and filename of current script;
# e.g., C:\Program\Script\test.ps1
$parentPath = split-path (split-path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -parent) -parent
# $parentPath contains C:\Program
```